# SurfaceView & Collision

Tags: android, surfaceview

in a BrickBreaker-game I have the following code to check the collision of the ball with the bar:

```
if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x && ball.x < bar.x + (bar.getWidth()/5)) {
        ...
    }

    else if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x + (bar.getWidth()/5) && ball.x < bar.x + (2*bar.getWidth()/5)) {
        ...
    }

    else if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x + (2*bar.getWidth()/5) && ball.x < bar.x + (3*bar.getWidth()/5)) {
        ...
    }

    else if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x + (3*bar.getWidth()/5) && ball.x < bar.x + (4*bar.getWidth()/5)) {
        ...
    }

    else if(ball.x + ball.getWidth() > bar.x + (4*bar.getWidth()/5) && ball.x < bar.x + bar.getWidth()) {
        ...
    }
```

but still if the ball doesn't hit the bar, it says, that a collision happened.
What's wrong with my collision checking?

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with my collision checking?

Wierd math. Check this [Circle-Rectangle collision detection (intersection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think, I've understood what you want to achieve. What about bar.y and ball.y? This code seems correct for me.

Comment: ty but i already solved my problem ;) I have bar.y and ball.y checking in my code but it didnt worked. I solved it with a complex mathematic calculation :)