# Checking a rectangle collision with a circle

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

I have two objects, a rectangle object and then a circular shaped object. At the moment i am using two rectangles to detect the collision of these objects, and although it is working the collision detectment is not accurate enough because using a rectangle means the collision is detected before the circle has actually been hit.

My question is what method could i use in order to detect the collision with the circle so that the collision is only detected when the rectangle actually intersects the circular object?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection. That question is not C#/xna specific, but contains several useful answers.

Comment: he's asking for methods to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using XNA you could create [BoundingSphere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.BoundingSphere.aspx) for the circle and [BoundingBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.BoundingBox.aspx) for the rectangle, then call `sphere.Intersects(box)` to check if they collide.

See that the `BoundingSphere` and the `BoundingBox` both have constructors that could fit your 2d needs