# Determine hit on vertical or horizontal wall on a rectangle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-physics, graphics2d

Currently i am working on bouncing a ball of a wall, in classic 2D-geometry.

The wall can be hit on both vertical and horizontal sides, and the result of the reflection depends on which side the ball hits.

I have tried some different solutions, but they just make me more confused.

How can i determine whether the ball is hitting a vertical or horizontal side of the wall?

PseudoCode for the overview:

```
iterate through each wall
if (collision between ball and wall)
  determine if vertical/horizontal hit
  calculate new velocity for ball
```

I use this code for collision detection and it works like a charm:
source: [Circle-Rectangle collision detection (intersection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection)

```
var isCollision = function (_projectile) {
    if(direction != undefined){
        var circleDistance = {};
        circleDistance.x = Math.abs(_projectile.getCenter().x - centerX);
        circleDistance.y = Math.abs(_projectile.getCenter().y - centerY);

        if (circleDistance.x > (width/2 + _projectile.getRadius())) { return false; }
        if (circleDistance.y > (height/2 + _projectile.getRadius())) { return false; }

        if (circleDistance.x <= (width/2)) { return true; }
        if (circleDistance.y <= (height/2)) { return true; }

        var cornerDistance_sq = square(circleDistance.x - width/2) + square(circleDistance.y - height/2);

        return (cornerDistance_sq <= (square(_projectile.getRadius())));
    }
    return false;
};

var square = function(_value){
    return _value * _value;
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think playing with some basic match of x and y positioning will tell you which wall the ball is hitting. However, please show some code that shows your effort on the technical side of things.

Answer (score 3):

**update after question update**

Asuming the ball has a direction/velocity vector `dx,dy` and has a radius of `r` (`ball.x`, `ball.y` are the ball positions of the ball center) do sth like this (have used similar in a billiard game, it is basic geometry and physics):

```
if (ball.x+ball.dx+r > wallV.x) ball.dx = -ball.dx // ball bounces off the 
vertical wall

if ( ball.y+ball.dy+r > wallH.y ) ball.dy = -ball.dy // ball bounces off horizontal wall
```

do similar for opposite walls if needed, since velocity vector changes, the new ball position after bouncing (or anyway) will be `ball.x += ball.dx; ball.y += ball.dy;`

[image]

**Bonus** if you add some **friction factor** (meaning the magnitudes of `dx` `dy` eventually fade away to zero, the ball eventually stops after following a path)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will implement this solution and see the result.
Cheers.

Comment: I just got a question: "wallV" and "wallH" in your example, are they different "wall-objects"? - Because i only work with identical square-walls. Or am i misunderstanding something in your code?

Comment: each wall will be located in different positions and orientations so a vertical wall (lets say `wallV`) will have certain `x,y` coordinates and a horizontal wall (lets say `wallH`) will have different and the test will have to know the positions of the walls to determine if ball bounces off there

Comment: each `wallV`, `wallH` etc can be instances of same object or class they just differ on their coordinates and orientations

Answer (score 2):

To solve properly a collision, you can't just test on X => if collision solve and return THEN test on y => if collision solve on y.
You have to check *which* axe (x OR y) collides first, and there's also the case when the ball hits two walls at the same time.
So you can't just reason with space : you have to deal with time, and compute an ETA -Estimated Time Arrival- for all walls, based on the ball speed (assuming walls are still).

pseudo code :

```
minETA = a too big number;
colliderList = [];
for (each wall in walls) {
   thisWallETA = computeETA(ball, wall);
   if (thisWallETA > minETA) continue;
   if (thisWallETA < minETA) {
      minETA = thisWallETA;
      colliderList.length = 0;
      colliderList.push(wall);
      continue;
   } 
   if (thisWallETA == minETA) {
      colliderList.push(wall);
      continue;          
   }
}
```

Then when the colliderList has only one item => solve on corresponding axe. If it has two items => solve on both axes.
Then increase the current time by minETA, and try again until the currentTime + minETA you found is > to thisCycleTime + thisCycleDt.

If you're interested, i might clarify some things up.

Good luck !