# Algorithm for accurate detection of overlap between a square and a circle?

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, collision-detection

I am implementing (in C++) a method to detect when an overlap is occurring between two static, axis-aligned shapes on a 2d plane. The shapes are either squares or circles, and therefore there are three cases I need to consider for overlap: square-square, circle-circle, and circle-square.

Square-square and circle-circle were simple enough, but I am struggling to find any solid information online about what the correct algorithm is for calculating square-circle overlap.

I am aware that I could embed the square inside a circle (or vice versa) as a rough method, but I'm interested in what would be considered the cleanest way to do this more precisely?

Researching it online suggests there is a 'correct' answer to this question, but it isn't made clear what exactly that answer is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection

Comment: More generally, find the closest point on the rectangle (square) to the center of the circle.  If the shape is AA, this is trivial.  If not, a dot product will give this.  If this distance is less than radius of circle, there is a collision.  Unless ciricle is completely within square, then you need to check each point for inclusion (distance of each vertex from center vs radius.)

Comment: The cleanest method depends on which information are stored for your figure. Is your circle modeled by the coordinate of 3 point, or you have the center and radius. And for your rectangle, idem 3 points, or anything else? If you provide me that I'll be happy to get back to high school mathematics!

Comment: Or I just give you a tip: let's `A` and `B` be the extremity of a side of your rectangle of lenght `l`, let's `C` be the center of the circle. Let's `d` be the distance of `C` to the line (AB), you have this relation `abs(ABxAC)=l*d` where `x` is the cross product AB and AC are vectors. Moreover the sign of the product can indicate weither the circul center is toward the inside or the outside.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple and fast algorithm:

```
bool doesSquareCircleOverlap(float squareCenterX, float squareCenterY, float squareHalfSize, float circleCenterX, float circleCenterY, float circleRadius) {
    float x = fabs(circleCenterX - squareCenterX) - squareHalfSize;
    float y = fabs(circleCenterY - squareCenterY) - squareHalfSize;

    if (x>0) {
        if (y>0) {
            return x*x + y*y<circleRadius*circleRadius;
        } else {
            return x<circleRadius;
        }
    } else {
        return y<circleRadius;
    }
}
```

Note that the square is represented by the center and *half-size*.

Basically, what it does is:

- it removes symmetrical cases with `fabs()`
- puts the corner into the origin
- checks which area the center of circle is, to determine the closest point on the square from the circle. If this closes point is nearer than `circleRadius`, then there is an overlap.