# Creating a mask layer in p5js

Tags: p5.js, generative-art

I would like to draw a pattern, and then only have that pattern ‘show through’ where it overlaps with a shape that I specify. Similar to how a mask layer works in Photoshop. Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715907/masking-or-clipping-mask-with-p5-js

Comment: No not exactly. That example shows a pre-loaded image() that uses the mask. I'd like to draw a pattern w/ p5 and then have part of that pattern showing through using the mask.

Comment: Also I'd like to be able to design a shape (using beginShape() / endShape()) for the mask, rather than using one of the basic shapes like the circle in the example.

Comment: Thank you for surfacing this though. Helpful for my learning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [masking, or clipping mask with p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715907/masking-or-clipping-mask-with-p5-js)

Answer (score 1):

I would use this 4 step process:

1. create your mask with beginShape()/endShape and a beginContour()/endContour() in the middle for the area to be shown.  You do this on a buffer.

   ```
   function setup() {
     createCanvas(400, 400);
     background(30)
     fill(200,50,60)
     msk = createGraphics(width,height)
     pattern = createGraphics(width,height)
     pixelDensity(1)
     msk.beginShape();
     // Exterior part of shape, clockwise winding
     msk.vertex(0, 0);
     msk.vertex(400, 0);
     msk.vertex(400, 400);
     msk.vertex(0, 400);
     // Interior part of shape, counter-clockwise winding
     msk.beginContour();
       msk.vertex(20, 20);
       msk.vertex(50, 220);
       msk.vertex(120, 380);
       msk.vertex(370, 320);
       msk.vertex(240, 160);
       msk.vertex(350, 40);
     msk.endContour();
     msk.endShape(CLOSE);
     mPixs = msk.loadPixels()
   }
   ```
2. Then create a different buffer for the pattern

   ```
   for (let c=0; c<9; c++) {
     for (let r=0; r<9; r++) {
       pattern.circle(width/8*c,height/8*r,40)
     }    
   }
   ```
3. Now load pixels from the mask and use the alpha value of each pixel on the alpha level of each corresponding pixel on the pattern.

   ```
   pattern.loadPixels()
   msk.loadPixels()
   for (let i=0; i < pattern.pixels.length; i+=4){
       pattern.pixels[i+3] = msk.pixels[i+3]
   }
   pattern.updatePixels()
   ```
4. Finally, just add the resulting buffer to your main canvas with `image(pattern,0,0)`

Take a look at this working example carefully coded just for you! :D

```js
let msk, pattern, mPixs
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(30)
  fill(200,50,60)
  msk = createGraphics(width,height)
  pattern = createGraphics(width,height)
  pixelDensity(1)
  msk.beginShape();
      // Exterior part of shape, clockwise winding
      msk.vertex(0, 0);
      msk.vertex(400, 0);
      msk.vertex(400, 400);
      msk.vertex(0, 400);
      // Interior part of shape, counter-clockwise winding
      msk.beginContour();
        msk.vertex(20, 20);
        msk.vertex(50, 220);
        msk.vertex(120, 380);
        msk.vertex(370, 320);
        msk.vertex(240, 160);
        msk.vertex(350, 40);
      msk.endContour();
  msk.endShape(CLOSE);
  mPixs = msk.loadPixels()
}

function draw() {
  
  for (let c=0; c<9; c++) {
    for (let r=0; r<9; r++) {
      pattern.circle(width/8*c,height/8*r,40)
    }    
  }
  for (let c=0; c<9; c++) {
    for (let r=0; r<9; r++) {
      let xo=random(-5,5), yo=random(-5,5)
      circle(width/8*c+xo,height/8*r+yo,50)
    }    
  }
  pattern.loadPixels()
  msk.loadPixels()
  for (let i=0; i < pattern.pixels.length; i+=4){
      pattern.pixels[i+3] = msk.pixels[i+3]
  }
  pattern.updatePixels()
  image(pattern,0,0)
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```