# LibGDX - Collision Detection | Collision Reaction | Collision doesn't apply to all?

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, collision

I have parent classes that create shape entities and I can choose to make the entity a collidable entity or a Non-Collidable Entity.
So far, in this project, Circles and Rectangles are collidables. Whereas, the ellipse is a Non-Collidable.
The funny thing is even though I have created multiple circles and rectangles. Only 1 pair of circles and rectangles are collidable whereas the rest isn't. I am really confused as I thought the child always inherits the property from the parent. Therefore, if all shapes have the same parent. I do not see how is it possible that the child does not behave the same way.

// CIRCLE ENTITY

```
public class daCircle extends Collidable{

    protected float circleRadius;
    protected int upKey;
    protected int downKey;
    protected int leftKey;
    protected int rightKey;

    public daCircle(int circleXPos, int circleYPos, float circleRadius, int circleSpeed, Color circleColor, 
    int upKey, int downKey, int leftKey, int rightKey) {
        super(circleXPos, circleYPos, circleColor, circleSpeed);
        this.circleRadius = circleRadius;
        super.keyMovementList.set(0, upKey);
        super.keyMovementList.set(1, downKey);
        super.keyMovementList.set(2, leftKey);
        super.keyMovementList.set(3, rightKey);
    }
}
```

// Collidable

```
public void checkForCollision(ArrayList<GeometricObjects> listOfAllShapes, String direction) {      
        for (GeometricObjects daShape : listOfAllShapes) {
            if (daShape instanceof Collidable) {
                Iterator<GeometricObjects> iter = listOfAllShapes.iterator();
                while(iter.hasNext()) {
                    GeometricObjects nextShape = iter.next();
                    if (daShape != nextShape) {
                        if (daShape instanceof daCircle && nextShape instanceof daCircle) {
                            setCirclesCollisionFlag(isCirclesColliding((daCircle)daShape, (daCircle)nextShape, direction));
                        }
                        if (daShape instanceof daRect && nextShape instanceof daRect) {
                            setRectanglesCollisionFlag(isRectanglesColliding((daRect)daShape, (daRect)nextShape, direction));
                        }
                        if (daShape instanceof daCircle && nextShape instanceof daRect ) {
                            setCircleRectangleCollisionFlag(circIntersectRect((daCircle)daShape, (daRect)nextShape, direction));
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

// Controller

```
public void movementController(ArrayList<GeometricObjects> allGeometricShapes) { 
        int temporaryObjSpeedHolder = 0;

        GeometricObjects daObject = (GeometricObjects) this;
        if (daObject instanceof Collidable) {
            collidableShape = (Collidable) daObject;
            daObject = collidableShape;
        }

        // if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        //     daObject.setXPos(Gdx.input.getX());
        //     daObject.setYPos(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY());
        // }

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(keyMovementList.get(0))){
            if (daObject instanceof Collidable) {
                collidableShape.checkForCollision(allGeometricShapes, "UP");
            }
            
            if (circlesAreColliding || rectanglesAreColliding || circleRectangleAreColliding) {
                temporaryObjSpeedHolder = incomingCollisionSpeed;
            } else {
                temporaryObjSpeedHolder = objectSpeed;
            }

            daObject.yPos += temporaryObjSpeedHolder;
        
        } else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(keyMovementList.get(1))){
            if (daObject instanceof Collidable) {
                collidableShape.checkForCollision(allGeometricShapes, "DOWN");
            }

            if (circlesAreColliding || rectanglesAreColliding || circleRectangleAreColliding) {
                temporaryObjSpeedHolder = incomingCollisionSpeed;
            } else {
                temporaryObjSpeedHolder = objectSpeed;
            }

            daObject.yPos -= temporaryObjSpeedHolder;

        }

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(keyMovementList.get(2))){
            if (daObject instanceof Collidable) {
                collidableShape.checkForCollision(allGeometricShapes, "LEFT");
            }

            if (circlesAreColliding || rectanglesAreColliding || circleRectangleAreColliding) {
                temporaryObjSpeedHolder = incomingCollisionSpeed;
            } else {
                temporaryObjSpeedHolder = objectSpeed;
            }

            daObject.xPos -= temporaryObjSpeedHolder;

        } else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(keyMovementList.get(3))){
            if (daObject instanceof Collidable) {
                collidableShape.checkForCollision(allGeometricShapes, "RIGHT");
            }

            if (circlesAreColliding || rectanglesAreColliding || circleRectangleAreColliding) {
                temporaryObjSpeedHolder = incomingCollisionSpeed;
            } else {
                temporaryObjSpeedHolder = objectSpeed;
            }

            daObject.xPos += temporaryObjSpeedHolder;
        }
```

I have created many circles and rectangles and discovered that only the latest created shapes are able to collide.
I thought that maybe since the shapes are all on different layers that it might not be able to collide.
I really dk what else I can be testing to see why it is the way it is. If you guys got suggestions of testing. I'm all for it!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you need this as additional check in your //Collidable code for all the possibilities ```daShape instanceof daRect && nextShape instanceof daCircle``` because they might not necessarily always be in this order ```daShape instanceof daCircle && nextShape instanceof daRect ``` i.e you might find a rect before a circle as you iterate which would be missed.

Comment: @londonBadger You are absolutely right. One of the problems I have now is that my circles are able to collide with my rectangle but my rectangles are not able to collide with my circle(Code crashes). I believe this has something to do with my conditional checks or at least the math logic of circIntersectRect. I am still trying to find ways to get my Rectangle to collide with my circle but i'm at an impasse. If you got any idea, I would love to try them!

Comment: If you are suspicious about your intersection test (and all this is axis-aligned), replace it with this one which seems optimised as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection

Comment: @londonBadger That is the one I am using! XD
UPDATE: I manage to get the Rectangle intersecting with the circle by tweaking the algorithm a little and account for the move position of the rectangle. However, I have a slight issue whereas if the rectangle collides into a shape from the left or right, they are unable to back out. Weird, I'll keep trying and update my progress!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your `checkForCollision` method.

You are iterating over all `GeometricObjects` in `listOfAllShapes`. Then you set the collision flag for the current iteration of the GeometricObject:

```
setCirclesCollisionFlag(isCirclesColliding((daCircle)daShape, (daCircle)nextShape, direction));
```

So if any collision is detected the flag will be set to true. **But if the next object doesn't collide, the flag is reset to false**. Therefore it seems that only the last shapes of each type in the iteration list can collide.

To fix this you need to change the lines `set...CollisionFlag ...` to **not reset the flag if it was already set to true**. Also you need to reset the flags once before the start of the loop.

A solution could look like this:

```
public void checkForCollision(ArrayList<GeometricObjects> listOfAllShapes, String direction) {
    // initially reset the flags before the loop
    setCirclesCollisionFlag(false);
    setRectanglesCollisionFlag(false);
    setCircleRectangleCollisionFlag(false);

    for (GeometricObjects daShape : listOfAllShapes) {
        if (daShape instanceof Collidable) {
            Iterator<GeometricObjects> iter = listOfAllShapes.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                GeometricObjects nextShape = iter.next();
                if (daShape != nextShape) {
                    if (daShape instanceof daCircle && nextShape instanceof daCircle //
                        && isCirclesColliding((daCircle)daShape, (daCircle)nextShape, direction)) { // only set to true, but never reset to false here
                        setCirclesCollisionFlag(true);
                    }
                    if (daShape instanceof daRect && nextShape instanceof daRect //
                        && isRectanglesColliding((daRect)daShape, (daRect)nextShape, direction)) { // only set to true, but never reset to false here
                        setRectanglesCollisionFlag(true);
                    }
                    if (daShape instanceof daCircle && nextShape instanceof daRect //
                        && circIntersectRect((daCircle)daShape, (daRect)nextShape, direction)) { // only set to true, but never reset to false here
                        setCircleRectangleCollisionFlag(true);
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I have tried your solution and played around with it a bit. Fully implementing the changes you have suggested.
I implemented part of your solution as shown here - https://imgur.com/a/CkJgIGf
This fixed the problem of the circle not being able to collide with the second rectangle.

Interesting enough, if I were to make changes to my isCirclesColliding and isRectanglesColliding collision check. When my circles collide with a circle or rectangle collide with a rectangle. They freeze in place. Probably has something to do with my conditions for movement.

But thx for your help.